# "HashMap is not a supported property type" - embedding a map with Objectify 4

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm trying to embed a map in an entity with Objectify 4 (and GAE SDK 1.9.0).

The [docs (here)](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities) show stuff like this:

```
@Embed
class LevelTwo {
    String bar;
}

@Entity
class EntityWithEmbeddedCollection {
    @Id Long id;
    List<LevelOne> ones = new ArrayList<LevelOne>();
}
```

So first I tried to do the same thing but with a HashMap< Long, LevelTwo >.  This resulted in a runtime error when I tried to save the entity.

Then I read about @EmbedMap, which is a recent addition to ofy.   So then I tried the following formlation:

```
class LevelTwo {
    Integer one;
    Boolean bee;
}

class EntityWithEmbeddedCollection {
    @Id Long id;
    @EmbeddedMap
    Map<Long, LevelTwo> ones = new HashMap<Long, LevelTwo>();
}
```

I also tried this with LevelTwo as an inner static class and a few other variations, but I always get:

```
com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException:
Error saving com.myapp.UserInfoSvr@96: items: java.util.HashMap is not a supported property type.
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.save(Transmog.java:105)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EmbedMap only works with String keys, and it works by creating an property on the entity that looks like "foo.bar.yourkeyhere". It's not a very sophisticated mechanism.

What exactly are you trying to do? You may also wish to consider the Mapify annotation and an embedded collection.

Comment: I want to use it in a variety of situations to map Long values (datastore Id's) to Objects or to Integers.  The number of entries will range from 5 to 500.  I had assumed that @ Map was just exposing a fairly sophisticated datastore feature.  Now that you have explained it, I think I should use @Serialize for now, and then consider alternatives when/if I need to query on the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Readers should note that on 2014-03-28 Objectify 4.1 was released and it makes a major change in the handling of embedding (which is relevant to this post).  It is a major improvement that was facilitated by a fairly recent improvement in Google's low-level datastore API.

The announcement is here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/sbhig-wCDnI